# Set SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowInstanceID value

Tags: workflow, splistitem, spfield, sql

I start worklfow programmaticaly on SPListItem (custom ContentType).
When i try to save all fields but "WorkflowInstanceID", its ok. But,

```
item[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowInstanceID] = "E714297B-E922-410A-9864-959F76A38686"
item.SystemUpdate()
```

throws Exception:

> SqlError: '@tp_WorkflowInstanceID is not a parameter for procedure proc_UpdateListItem.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 8145 State: 1 Class: 16 Procedure: 'proc_UpdateListItem'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorkflowInstanceID is only retreivable, it not possible to update this property, [as stated in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.workflowcontext.workflowinstanceid%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

This is the unique GUID of the workflow instance, and is what SharePoint uses to identify the instance.

EDIT: And by the way, the title of this question is a bit confusing.

```
SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowInstanceID
```

only returns the GUID of the Field that you want to update, hence you are not trying to update SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowInstanceID, but the value of that field in an instance.